# golang tcp router

Tags: golang, tcp, router

Есть ли аналог роутеров (аля gorilla/gin gonic) для tcp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Протокол TCP проще представить как `io.Reader` и `io.Writer`. Таким образом, чтение из подключения, это чтение того, что туда записано с другого конца. И запись, это то, что должно быть прочитано с другой стороны. Т.е. записывать можно что угодно. Любые данные.

#### Коротко об HTTP

Протокол HTTP имеет маршрутизацию, т.к. имеется некоторая договорённость. Например запрос GET, как чистый текст будет выглядеть так

```
GET /user/1 HTTP/1.1
```

При этом, конец строки `\r\n`. И возможны некоторые заголовки, например

```
GET /user/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip deflate
Authorization: Bearer token
```

Если запрос имеет тело, то заголовок от тела отделается пустой строкой.

#### TCP маршрутизация

Таким образом, чтобы иметь возможность маршрутизировать TCP запросы, нужна некая договорённость о том, что такое запрос и как кодировать.

В общем случае, это договорённость о формате сообщения, - его длине, маршруте, - пересылаемом по TCP. Так же, необходимо продумать максимально допустимые размеры сообщений, чтобы не получить перерасход оперативной памяти при неправильно составленном сообщении.

Таким образом, декодировав сообщение, можно использовать извлечённый из него маршрут.

---

- Существуют готовые системы пересылки сообщений, по постоянному TCP-подключению. Например, [mangos](https://github.com/nanomsg/mangos), который воплощает протокол Nanomsg (SP - Scalable Protocol), довольно гибкий, но сложный.
- Так же, в стандартной библиотеке существует пакет [net/textproto](https://godoc.org/net/textproto), который позволяет создать свои текстовые протоколы.
- Помимо этого, существуют различные RPC - инструменты для вызова удалённых процедур, такие как [net/rpc](https://godoc.org/net/rpc) или [gRPC](https://grpc.io/).